# C++11 regex to match nothing

Tags: c++, regex, c++11, stl

I encountered a task which reuires a regex matching nothing.

C++ reference happily states that it already has such thing:
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/basic_regex/basic_regex

> 1) Default constructor. Constructs an empty regular expression which will **match nothing**.

But in reality (clang 3.3) it happens not to be the case:

```
#include <string>
#include <regex>

int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {

    std::regex re1;
    std::regex re2("");
    std::smatch rt1, rt2;

    bool r1 = std::regex_match(std::string(""), rt1, re1);
    bool r2 = std::regex_match(std::string(""), rt2, re2);
    std::cerr << "r1:" << r1 << ", r2:" << r2 << std::endl;
}
```

This program prints: `r1:1, r2:1`
What should mean that both regexes matched empty string.

Any idea what is wrong here and how to create "match nothing" regex ?

Comment: By "nothing", do you mean `^$`?

Comment: There's an empty string at the beginning of each string, that's what it's matching.

Comment: @Barmar there's also the argument that an empty match pattern represents the universally accepting DFA `({q}, S, {q*S->q}, q, {q}})`, for some abstract charset `S` and (q*S->q meaning forall s in S, qxs->q)

Comment: @Dfr: so you want a regex which never reports any match, right?  As opposed to one which matches the absence of content?

Comment: It would be more accurate to say that the default regex matches only an empty string.

Comment: @John, yes, also want to clearly understand what behaviour to expect from `re1` (regex constructed with empty constructor) and how it differs from `re2` (regex constructed with empty string)

Comment: `clang` gives me `false`. Are you linking against GNU `libstdc++` by any chance?

Comment: @Cubbi, i guess so, i'm using clang in Fedora which itself depends on `libstdc++`

Comment: @Dfr in that case, you should use boost.regex. The GNU libstdc++ regex library was just non-functional stubs until the current 4.9

Comment: This clears things out, need to upgrade or use boost.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default constructor for `std::basic_regex` constructs a regular expression that "does not match any character sequence". [re.regex.construct]/1. If your implementation matches an empty character sequence it's wrong.